# Google Analytics - Sub-domains set as referring sites

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

Just want to thank everyone in advance for the help and information gathered.

Here is basically what I'm trying to accomplish:

- I need sub-domain visitor statistics to be tracked in a
  single profile, show up as the referring site and still allow for event tracking

I have read this, http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName, but I am just unclear if what I am looking for can be done by setting the domain name to 'www.example.com'.

Again, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the first part of your request the documentation nails it:  "[do this...] if you want to track visitor behavior across sub-domains in the same profile"

As for storing the subdomains as a referral, it only takes a day to test.  The documentation, as you said, isn't too clear on that but if they are being tracked as separate entities within the same profile I would imagine you can see the referring traffic data in the traffic sources section of GA.

Good luck!

Comment: could also use a custom variable/metric and pop it on the page. Use javascript to parse out the referring domain and if it's the current domain but different subdomain, push that value into the custom var/metric.  Then look at the report(s) for that metric.